# async function in mvc4 vb.net

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

i have the below structure :

this is my controller :

```
   Public Function InsertRegistration() as string

          dim res = t.Insertregistration(jsonparam.status)

          return res
   End Function
```

this is my class :

```
   Public Function InsertRegistration(byval status as string) as string

         sql.Insertregistration(status)

         return "1"

   End Function
```

this is my model function :

```
    Public Function InsertRegistration(ByVal status As String) As Boolean
    Dim TConnSQL As New SqlConnection(sql)
    Dim CommSQL As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("JK_SP_INSERT_PROFILE", TConnSQL)
    Dim paramSQL As SqlClient.SqlParameter
    Dim data_ada As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As DataSet
    Try

        CommSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        paramSQL = New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@STATUS", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)
        paramSQL.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        paramSQL.Value = STATUS
        CommSQL.Parameters.Add(paramSQL)

        CommSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()

        InsertRegistration= True

    Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
        WriteToText("Nbl.InsertRegistration", ex.ToString)
        InsertRegistration= False
    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteToText("Nbl.InsertRegistration", ex.ToString)
        InsertRegistration= False
    Finally
        If (IsNothing(CommSQL) = False) Then CommSQL.Dispose()
        If TConnSQL.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then TConnSQL.Close()
    End Try
End Function
```

is there a way to return the result `1` in an asynchronous way that the function `sql.Insertregistration(status)` keeps running in background after i return the result to the client?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your function `sql.Insertregistration(status)` as in below code:

```
(new Task<bool>(() =>
{
    return sql.Insertregistration(status);
})).Start();
```

Note: Please take care of the cross thread ooperations.